# Templated class: How to create instance and work with it?

Tags: arduino-nano, class

I have created a class like this:

```
#ifndef MyList_h
#define MyList_h

#include "Arduino.h"

template <typename T>
class MyList {
public:  
  MyList(void); 
  ~MyList(void);

  void addItem(T* item);

  //more stuff

};

#endif
```

And implementation is like this:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "MyList.h"

template<typename T> MyList<T>::MyList(void) {
  // constructor implementation here
}

template<typename T> MyList<T>::~MyList(void) {
  // desctructor implementation here
}

template<typename T> void MyList<T>::addItem(T* item) {
  // function implementation here
}

// ...more stuff
```

In my .ino Sketch I'm doing this (found this solution in a C++ example):

```
#include "MyList.h"
MyList<word>* list = new MyList<word>(); // global scope
//... more stuff
```

But when compiling, Arduino IDE complains:

> Test.ino:5: undefined reference to `MyList::MyList()'

I googled a bit and found this alternative way for creating the instance:

```
ArrayList<word>* list;
```

Then there's no error, just compiles file. BUT as soon as I want to use this instance (=adding code) like this:

```
list->addItem(i);
```

compiler complains again:

> Test.ino:25: undefined reference to `MyList::addItem(unsigned int*)'

What's wrong? Why is this reference undefined?

I tried another way:

```
ArrayList<word> list; // again global scope
```

But then the compiler also tells me:

> Test.ino:5: undefined reference to `MyList<unsigned
>   int>::MyList()' /tmp/ccp8qmCz.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function`
>   _GLOBAL__sub_D_list':
>   /....../Test.ino:5:
>   undefined reference to `MyList::~MyList()'

So, how can I create an instance of my class that uses a template?

---

Environment: Arduino IDE 1.8.3 (I know, I could update...) + Arduino Nano Board.

Comment: You need to combine the header and source into a single header file.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution:

According to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752837/undefined-reference-to-template-class-constructor

--> Put all implementation in .h file. That's it. No more compler complains, code runs fine.

I think I have to dig deeper into c/c++ development ...